# inherit Angular parent directive attribute with isolate scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to inherit an attribute from a parent custom directive with isolate scope.  In the example below, I want to be able to access the api attribute on myParent from the myChild controller or link function.  My end goal is to inject an instance of the api that can be accessed by the children and from the view controller.

```
<my-parent api="parentInstance1">
    <my-child ng-repeat="field in ::data"
        ng-attr-src="{{field.src||undefined}}"
    </my-child>        
</my-parent>

<my-parent api="parentInstance2">
    <my-child ng-repeat="field in ::data"
        ng-attr-src="{{field.src||undefined}}"
    </my-child>
</my-parent>
```

A simplified version of both directives looks like this

```
app.directive('myParent', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            api: '=?'
        },
        template: '...',
        controller: function ($scope, $attrs ) {

            // foo is injected from a factory instance
            function foo ( ) {

            }

            $scope.api = {
                foo: foo
            }
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {

        }
    }
});

app.directive('myChild', function () {
    return {
        require: "^myParent",
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            api: '=?'                
        },
        template: "...",
        controller: function ( $scope ) {
            // I want to access $scope.api in link or controller            
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
            // I want to access $scope.api in link or controller
        }
    }
});
```

I can't access $scope.api from the child directive but $scope.parentInstance1 and $scope.parentInstance2 are visible.  I realise I can just explicitly declare  but I'd rather understand how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you are referencing `parentInstance1` and `parentInstance2` on `my-parent` but the attributes on `my-child` are in `myParent`'s `$scope` so you can reference the actual `$scope.api` object that is on `myParent`'s `$scope` in the attributes of the `my-child` directive tag and then reference the name of the attribute in the isolate scope definition of the `myChild` directive.

```
<my-child inner-api="api"></my-child>
```

.. and then in the child directive...

```
app.directive('myChild', function () {    
...
scope: {
   innerApi: '=?'
}
...
controller: function($scope) {
   $scope.innerApi  // <- accessible in the controller
}
```

Heres a [simplified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hally9k/jtL81vo4/)...

Comment: Yes this would be the way to go.

Comment: I've tried applying this method to my code but it seems to break with ng-repeat (or possibly ng-transclude wrapping the my-child> applied.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the OP that <myParent> has replace:true and a transcluded div wrapping the <myChild ng-repeat> directives in the template.

Comment: Have you tried putting the ng-repeat inside the template as apposed to instantiating a new directive instance on each iteration? Please include a fiddle in your answer to be explicit about the particular issue you are having.